# poll returns 0 in bash but works as expected in tcsh

Tags: c, bash, input, system-calls, tcsh

I'm using sshfs and I face a strange behaviour regarding the poll system call.

```
    while (1) {
    struct pollfd fds[2];

    fds[0].fd = sshfs.rfd;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    fds[1].fd = sshfs.ptyfd;
    fds[1].events = POLLIN;
    res = poll(fds, 2, timeout);
    if (res == -1) {
        perror("poll");
        return -1;
    }
    if (res == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Timeout waiting for prompt\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (fds[0].revents) {
        /*
         * Something happened on stdout of ssh, this
         * either means, that we are connected, or
         * that we are disconnected.  In any case the
         * password doesn't matter any more.
         */
        break;
    }

    res = read(sshfs.ptyfd, &c, 1);
    if (res == -1) {
        perror("read");
        return -1;
    }
    if (res == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EOF while waiting for prompt\n");
        return -1;
    }
    buf[len] = c;
    len++;
    if (len == passwd_len) {
        if (memcmp(buf, passwd_str, passwd_len) == 0) {
            write(sshfs.ptyfd, sshfs.password,
                  strlen(sshfs.password));
        }
        memmove(buf, buf + 1, passwd_len - 1);
        len--;
    }
}
```

while in tcsh the code actually accepts input and able to process further, in bash, no input is accepted, and then after 60 seconds, it timeouts (the timeout that is assigned for this syscall).
Why those shells behave differently, and how I can make bash accept the password without reprogramming the code?

I tried to run the code both in bash and tcsh, but only in tcsh it works as expected.

Edit: It seems that in a nested scenario. (tcsh on bash on tcsh for example), it doesn't work.

Comment: No problem, though the code is of sshfs'

Comment: This is _literally unbelievable_ unless there's other code written in shell that controls how this tool is started that you aren't showing us. When a shell simply runs another program without any redirections it doesn't change stdin/stdout/stderr at all but just passes them through; the shell _can't_ change what the program being run does with those descriptors after it's started.

Comment: Now, if the C program is on the receiving end of a pipeline from a shell, or reading a heredoc/herestring, &c., _then_ that might make sense. If it's interacting with a terminal where the shell did some `stty`-style manipulation, _that_ might make sense. But otherwise/generally, when a shell starts a C executable as a subprocess, _the shell has no control over the file descriptors that subprocess inherits_. Ideally, a question should cover all steps needed for someone else to see the problem themselves; that way the necessary moving parts for reproduction can be identified.

Comment: See the [mre] definition; roughly, a "MRE" is the shortest possible code someone else can copy/paste/run themselves _without changes_ to see the same problem. If I can't copy/paste the C code you gave into my own compiler and see the problem myself, then I can't test my answers, nor can I trace execution (with tools like `strace`, `sysdig`, &c) to see what's going on at runtime. (If you'd provided something I could run myself, we'd have much less problem with disbelief, too!)

Comment: (btw, to be clear, if running this down myself, `strace -s 2048 -o test-bash.strace -f bash -c '...'` vs `strace -s 2048 -o test-tcsh.strace -f tcsh -c '...'` is _exactly_ how I'd start, since it provides a trace you can use to see both exactly _how_ the syscalls are behaving differently, but also what was done to the FDs previously -- which other calls were done during TTY configuration or the like, if any; but for a noninteractive shell there shouldn't be any TTY configuration at all in the first place).

Comment: (...mind, if this problem happens with interactive shells only and not with noninteractive shells, that's a _big_ clue... and another thing the question doesn't currently provide details/tools to make testable).